# JpaTransactionManager doesn't rollback transaction

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I use JHipster to make a simple app and write a service, code as follows:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class OperateQueueActionService {
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
    public OperateQueueDTO apply(OperateQueueDTO operateQueueDTO, QueueEventType queueEventType, String deskNo) {
    StateMachine<QueueStatus, QueueEventType> stateMachine = operateQueueActionMachineService.getStateMachine();
    try {   QueueEventDTO operateQueueEventDTO = operateQueueUtils.saveQueueEvent(operateQueueDTO, queueEventType, deskNo); 
         ......in process will throw RuntimeException.
        } finally {
           stateMachine.stop();
       }
    }
}
```

I want the transaction to rollback and not save `queueEvent`, but the record is saved in the database. This is the transaction log:

> `[2018-07-24 12:04:51.861] [XNIO-2 task-6] WARN 
>   o.s.s.l.CompositeStateMachineListener -Error during stateContext
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: 无效状态  at
>   com.higoee.queue.state.utils.OperateQueueStateMachineLogListener.stateContext(OperateQueueStateMachineLogListener.java:58)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [2018-07-24 12:04:51.871]
>   [XNIO-2 task-6] INFO  c.h.q.s.u.OperateQueueStateMachineLogListener
>   -4d667539-3316-491d-a0db-240e29b0fcae状态机状态为：STATEMACHINE_STOP [2018-07-24 12:04:51.872] [XNIO-2 task-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager -Initiating transaction commit
>   [2018-07-24 12:04:51.874] [XNIO-2 task-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager -Committing JPA transaction on
>   EntityManager`

Comment: how does operateQueueUtils look like?

Comment: @ Service
@ Transactional
public class OperateQueueUtils {public OperateQueueDTO save(OperateQueueDTO operateQueueDTO) {OperateQueueDTO operateQueueDTO1 = operateQueueService.save(operateQueueDTO);
        sendQueueChangeNotifyMsg(operateQueueDTO1);
        return operateQueueDTO1;
    }

Comment: public QueueEventDTO saveQueueEvent(OperateQueueDTO operateQueueDTO, QueueEventType queueEventType,String deskNo) {QueueEventDTO queueEventDTO = new QueueEventDTO();queueEventDTO.setOpinion(operateQueueDTO.getDescription());
        return queueEventService.save(queueEventDTO);

Comment: my database is Oracle

Answer (score 0):

JPA config have not problem,spring state machine had been catch the exception which was thrown in StateMachineListenerAdapter.